# UTF8 Text file reading problem .net

Tags: csv, utf-8, odbc, ole

I have a CSV file that is UTF8 encoded.  I would like to read it in using ODBC or OLE and the MS Jet Engine, but I cant find a connection string that supports UTF8.  I have seen CharacterSet=ANSI AND CharacterSet=Unicode but not CharacterSet=UTF8.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I discovered you can specify a numeric code page value for the CharacterSet property, e.g. CharacterSet=65001 for UTF8.